# Implement cross platform push notification azure notification hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, cross-platform, azure-notificationhub

I need to implement push notification system which allows to send push to specific users every time.

the registration to the hub is supported by device token and set of tags.

Is the right way to do what I want is to register each user with a singleton set of tags with their user ID as the only tag?

and then when I'd like to send push notifications to users a,b,c for example I will need to attach their users Id's.

Is there any way more elegant to do so or those tags are the only way?

BTW I am limited to attach 20 tags foreach push Im sending so I wont be able to push to more then 20 specific users at once.

Please let me know what you think about this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Liran Revivo well i think, yes this is the right way to do push notification over azure.

As my experience with azure push notification

step 1: i made a notificationHub for my azure notification and registered my GCM api key with that hub

step 2: i did register device token with or without the tag as you want.

step 3: send push notification

> i sent push with different case like:

(i)  sends a push to single device: i just sent with that particular device token registration id

(ii)     sends a push for a group of device: So i mentioned tag name and sent the push

(iii)    sends a push for multiple group: So i mentioned multiple tag name and sent the push

(iv)  sends a push to all devices: So i send tag name empty and by deafult it sent to all device with that notificationHub

By doing all these above stuff, i did my push notification with azure, And i think this is the right way to push with azure as it is documented by its offical site

Comment: Hi, You wrote: 
(i) sends a push to single device: i just sent with that particular device token. So do you save device tokens in your database for that matter?

Comment: yes also stored the token for my future requirement

Comment: @Liran Revivo but when register your device with the notificationhub you will get the registration id by the help of that you can send notification to that particular device, so that you have to also carry in your db

Comment: Actually I am looking for an efficient way to do so, Since my Users table already contains an Id field of course, I would like to use that same Id in order to notify that specific user. Hope that can be achieved by using tags, but tomorrow I guess it would be a good idea to check whether I can set my own registration Id that you mentioned, so I would set it to be User Id.. Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience - using user ID as a TAG works quite well. It allows you to send push for specific user. If you want to notify all users at once, you can send push notification without specific tag, then it would work as a broadcast message. On the other hand if you want to divide users to some subgroups you can provide them some "channels" using specific tags.

For example
"premium_user" tag that every premium user registers.